# grep in bash-script doesn't print message in log file

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, stdout

I'm trying to write the output of a command to a log file using grep:

```
./exeFile dir1/file.conf | grep textError > logTest.txt &
```

But it doesn't write anything to the log file.

If I use `./exeFile dir1/file.conf > logTest.txt &` instead of the above command the output will be written to the log file without any problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, when you are using `> logTest.txt`, you are simply redirecting stdout to the logTest.txt so you can't see anything.

To see what the problem is, run your grep without redirecting the stdout to a file:

```
./exeFile dir1/file.conf | grep textError
```

See if you have any output to redirect in the first place, maybe your grep does not have any results at all.

So first make sure your grep is working, then redirect the output.

In your second command, you are redirecting all of the output and you are not filtering anything, thats why the second command works.

Comment: If I use "./exeFile dir1/file.conf | grep textError" in console I have correct result. But if I add "./exeFile dir1/file.conf | grep textError > logTest.txt" - log file is clear

Comment: When redirecting output to the file, do you receive any output on terminal?

Comment: No, In the terminal there is nothing

Comment: Can you post exactly the command you run?